# only translation keys displayed after upgrade to angular 7 (ngx-tranlsate)

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have a problem using angular 7 version combined with ngx-translate. It seems that after the upgrade to 7.2.15 ngx-tranlsate does not initialize TranslationService properly. In `app.module` I have following configuration:

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpTranslateLoaderFactory,
                deps: [
                    HttpClient
                ]
            }
        })
```

And a factory class that exports:

```
export function HttpTranslateLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

In `TranslateHttpLoader` class resources from asset folder are fetched but after the upgrade to angular 7 they are not listed in the network (DevTools) tab as downloaded resource. As a result only translation keys are displayed in all views.

Does anybody know what can be the problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't this be in app.module.ts ? And can you show the way you're using translate in your template files?

Comment: you are right it is in app.module.ts. I will edit the question. This is the way I am usiing it in the templates: `<h3 class="content-title">{{'Features.Alerts.System Info' | translate}}</h3>`

Comment: export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

Your httpLoader doesnt seem to return the path to assets properly, can it be the case?

Comment: in the constructor of `TranslateHttpLoader` I havethese paths:
`private readonly prefix: string = './assets/i18n/lang/',
private readonly suffix: string = '.json'`

Comment: Could you look into your console? Maybe you would see failed requests there, that the ngx-translate trying to make, but doesn't find the files? Maybe that'll help

Comment: No failing requests in network tab. I believe it does not even execute any request for downloading asset files.